# Python dynamically select values from comma separated values

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following strings:

```
University of example1
Assistent professor, hello, University of example2
Hello, University of example3
```

How can I retrieve only the values that contain "University" so that the output will be as follows?

```
University of example1
University of example2
University of example3
```

Comment: XPath is designed to select parts of an XML document.  Why would you want to use XPath without XML?

Comment: Yeah I use XML, but i'm busy with a project in Python scrapy. So I scraped my XML and put in an array. But then I perceived that some of the values in my array weren't were still separated by commas. However, I only need the University values to be in my array. If it is not possible to do such a thing in xml, I will look for other options in python. Tnx for your comment

Comment: Post your XML if you want to use XPath; otherwise, rewrite and retag your question for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take each String, split it by comma, and then check each slice for "University".

```
data = """University of example1
Assistent professor, hello, University of example2
Hello, University of example3"""

data = data.replace("\n",",")   #All one line, split with commas
slices = data.split(",")        #Get each slice
for slice in slices:            #Go through each slice
    if "University" in slice:   #check for magic word
        print slice.strip()     #print out what matches, remove trailing and leading white space
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your string into an array with [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) then use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) or a list comprehension to filter out the ones you don't need.

Something like the below should work:

```
# This will probably come from your file IRL
# We want a list of strings that we can split later and parse
plaintext = """University of example1
Assistent professor, hello, University of example2
Hello, University of example3"""
lines = plaintext.splitlines()


# Define a function to pass into filter
# You'll want to change this to taste, maybe use a regexp depending on requirements
def is_uni(text):

    # Strip out any leading spaces
    return text.lstrip().startswith("Uni")

for line in lines:
    for uni in filter(is_uni,line.split(',')):
        print uni
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data_string = "University of example1
Assistent professor, hello, University of example2
Hello, University of example3"
valid_strings = []
strings = data_string.split(",")
for string in strings:
    if "University" in string:
        valid_strings.append(string)
```

Use `valid_strings` as you will.